# Why the Castelnuovo exact sequence is named after Castelnuovo

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview

I have seen variations of the following exact sequence referred throughout the literature as the *Castelnuovo sequence*:

$$0\longrightarrow \mathscr I_{X:H}(-d)\longrightarrow \mathscr I_X\longrightarrow \mathscr I_{X\cap H,H}\longrightarrow 0$$
where $X\subset\mathbb P^n$ is some scheme and $H$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$.  The proof is straightforward from the definition of ideal quotients.

In what context did it first appear, and why is it named after Castelnuovo?

Comment: I don't think I understand your notation, so I dont' guarentee this is on point.  I f you look at the bound Castelnuovo provides for the geometric genus of a curve in projective space it involves understanding the hypersurfaces of a given degree d containing the curve and exact sequences similar to yours occur.  You could look in 'Geometry of Algebraic Curves' for this Castelnuovo result.